# Kivy bugs when I press win+v in an edit window

Tags: python, kivy

```
<UI>:
title: 'InputDialog'
auto_dismiss: False

RelativeLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    pos: self.pos
    size: root.size

    TextInput:
        id: input
        hint_text:'test'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.725}
        size_hint: 0.95, 0.5


    Label:
        id: output
        size_hint: 0.95, 0.25
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 0.5}
```

I have this UI file in Kivy. It works as expected, except that if I press windows + v, I can't paste in text like I can in any other windows programme. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: do you mean `Ctrl+V` which paste text from clipboard ?

Comment: @furas No, windows has a new clipboard feature that shows the clipboard history with win + v

Comment: did you try `Ctrl+V` which works on all systems ?

Comment: @furas Yes this does work, but the win+v option is still supposed to work.

Comment: Presumably win+v requires the application to do something that Kivy doesn't do. I couldn't find anything about using this feature with sdl2 (your likely window backend) on a quick google search. Assuming it requires some action on Kivy's part, it seems safe to say we don't support this.